MacBook M1 Pro randomly shutdown and the audio and video doesn’t work. What can be done to fix this?
I have a MacBook M1 Pro. I bought it 2 years ago. All of sudden it shuts down randomly and doesn’t turn on. The audio and video is also not working.The video is playing, but the scenes aren’t loading.. it’s the timer that keeps running.. also the audio is also not working
I took it to Apple Care and they said they couldn’t recognise. I did a SMC reset and mac seems to work fine.. not getting shut down that frequently.. earlier it was so random.. like thrice in a day.. but now it’s been on for 3 days continuously.. but the audio and video is not working… I did a factory reset..but he audio and video problem still persists. What should I do to make the audio and video run fine?
